# How to echo woocomerce attributes values in dropdown box

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

How to echo woocomerce attributes values in dropdown box, as im creating enquiry form. for the same i need echo the values in dropdown

Comment: Had tried with $product = wc_get_product();
echo $product->get_attribute( 'GSM' );
global $product;

Comment: But need to echo the values in dropdown

Comment: The attributes of a specific product? Or all the possible attribute values?

Comment: yes of  specific product and specific attribute